# List Comprehension Using any() Creating Multiple Entries in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

I have a scenario where I have created a list of keywords, and I'm iterative over the rows of a dataframe to determine a column value if another column contains any words from my keyword list in it.  Here is an example:

```
kwrds = ['dog', 'puppy', 'golden retriever']

df = pd.DataFrame({
'description': ['This is a puppy', 'This is a dog', 'This is a golden retriever type dog', 'This is a cat', 'this is a kitten'],
'name': ['Rufus', 'Dingo', 'Rascal', 'MewMew', 'Jingles'],
'species': []})

for i,r in df.iterrows():
    if any([x in r['description'] for x in kwrds]):
          df.at[i, 'species'] = 'Canine'
    else:
          df.at[i, 'species'] = 'Feline'
```

The looping itself seems to work fine, however I am running into an issue where sometimes the species column will end up with multiple entries like

```
CanineCanineCanineCanine
```

Where other times it will work fine.

From what I understand the list comprehension itself should only return a true or false value.  It almost seems like the row is getting iterated over multiple times, but with the same index, so the entry is created over and over.

The problem I'm thinking with that thought though is that it is not happening for every row in the dataframe.  Only some, and generally always towards the end of the dataframe.

I'm not even sure where to start on trying to diagnose this issue.

Comment: THAT code will never produce the results you describe.  That particular code snippet works just fine (once I fill in dummy values for `'species'`).  You said "sometimes"; what does that mean?  When does it fail?

Comment: @TimRoberts correct, I tried to simplify down my notebook I'm working in to minimize the code in place.  Prior to this process coming in I actually have several different dataframes that I concat together, drop and add some columns, etc.  After typing the question I thought that it might be an issue with needed to reset the index on the dataframe after the previous work was done but that didn't resolve the issue either.  Also, at the end, I do a pivot_table on the dataframe to sum values contained in it.  Starting to think maybe thats the problem?? Not sure.

Comment: Yes, running `sum` on a text column is going to concatenate the results.

Comment: Ah thank you.  That solved the issue.  I had a df.groupby().sum() instance later in the code and I had left 'Species' out of the groupby columns and it was trying to sum the Species column.  Adding this fixed the issue.

Comment: As an aside, you should probably just avoid `iterrows` and `.iat`, just use a list comprehension and assign the the whole column: `df['species'] = ['canine' if any(word in desc for word in kwrds) else 'feline' for desc in df['description']]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['Species'] = np.where(df.description.str.contains("|".join(kwrds)), 'Canine', 'Feline')

df
                           description     name Species
0                      This is a puppy    Rufus  Canine
1                        This is a dog    Dingo  Canine
2  This is a golden retriever type dog   Rascal  Canine
3                        This is a cat   MewMew  Feline
4                     this is a kitten  Jingles  Feline
```